# IPv6 link-local multicast stops working after a reconnection

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ipv6, multicast

I have two microcontroller boards with the same Wifi module. One of the boards acts as an Access Point (AP) while the other acts as a Station (STA) trying to connect with the AP when it is in range.

I am only using link-local IPv6 addresses. The strange thing is that if I ping on the link-local multicast address (ff02::1) it works the first time that the STA connects to the AP. After I disconnect and reconnect to the AP, I can not ping to the link-local multicast address anymore although I can ping to the IPv6 link-local address(fe80:xx) of the AP.

If I reset the interface on the STA side, I can ping again to the STA. Any ideas how I can resolve the problem of the link local address being not reachable ? The entire process has to be automated, i.e. no interaction from the user should be required.

Here is an example session:

**STA connects to AP for the first time**

> wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211 -iwlan0

**Link-local multicast works fine**

> ping6 -I wlan0 ff02::1

**Disconnect and reconnect**

> killall wpa_supplicant
> wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211 -iwlan0

**Link-local multicast does not work**

> ping6 -I wlan0 ff02::1
> connect: Network is unreachable

**Link only unicast works fine**

> ping6 -I wlan0 fe80:xx

**Bringing the network interface up and down solves the problem**

> ip link set wlan0 down && ip link set wlan0 up
> ping6 -I wlan0 ff02::1 #works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the systemd network device files. Just deleting those files and rebooting solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).